# Why is Sonar GitLab Plugin not sending analyze results to gitlab as a comments while using default templates?

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, gitlab, sonarqube-scan

I currently have a jenkins job that is triggered when push or commit is maded within a gitlab project with use of a configurated webhooks. Everything works fine and projects are analysed when they're supposed to with SonarQube scanner for maven method, the problem is I want to then push SonarQube analyze results to a given project in form of global or inline comments. So I have installed on my sonarQube server [Sonar Gitlab plugin](https://github.com/gabrie-allaigre/sonar-gitlab-plugin) . Problem is it's not making those comments with results.

I have used default templates for global and inline comments as are stated in plugin documentation. My gitlab configuration on my SonarQube server looks like this:

[SonarQubeConfig1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DRoe0.png) - The gitlab name is direct https link directly to a repository

[SonarQubeConfig2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/406gw.png) - FreeMarker syntax configuration in global and inline comments is directly from the default template which you can find in Sonar Gitlab Plugin

[SonarQubeConfig3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aYkeN.png)

I haven't added any other configuration in connection with this except from the ones I have staed in my post, thanks.

Comment: did you get this to work? I am trying to do the same and have no luck so far.

Comment: Not yet, been trying to do deal with this even with sonar gitlab plugin creator but there is not much traffic in there so there Is not many people who could help. I'm however starting to have a feeling that you need gitlab enterprise edition in order to do this.

Comment: @Patrick, were you correct in that you needed enterprise edition? I've been trying to get this work with community edition and I'm getting exceptions like: "To use the property "sonar.branch.name" and analyze branches, Developer Edition or above is required. "

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got this working, the difference is that I have Jenkins for CI/CD and I am not using the GitLab CI/CD. Here is what I had to do:

1. While executing the sonar scan I had to pass the below properties:

   - sonar.analysis.mode=preview
   - sonar.branch=$GIT_BRANCH
   - sonar.gitlab.project_id={project_ID_from_GitLab}
   - sonar.gitlab.commit_sha=$GIT_COMMIT
   - sonar.gitlab.ref_name=$GIT_BRANCH

SonarQube needs to be run in the preview mode for it to publish the results in GitLab.

- Setup the GitLab URL and user access token on the SonarQube server.
- Make sure the GitLab certificate is trusted on the JRE/CACerts on the Sonar Server and the scanner server.
- Step 1: Browse to your GitLab URL in Firefox
- Step 2: Click on the lock button next to the URL

[image]

- Step 3: Click on secure connection -> more information
- Step 4: Click on view certificate -> Details -> Export
- Step 5: Save the crt file
- Step 6: On the Sonar server/scanner - open an Admin command prompt
- Step 7: Browse to the Go to your *java_home\jre\lib\security* folder
- Step 8: run the following command, this will add the GitLab certificate to your Java trusted certificate list.

  ```
  keytool -import -alias example -keystore  "C:\Program Files\Java\jre_version\lib\security\cacerts" -file pathtothefile.cer
  ```

  Let me know if this works for you.

*Edit* - adding Jenkins configuration screenshot.
[image]

Comment: By a Jenkins for CI/CD you mean that you have the code that runs the analysis and then posts it to a gitlab in a Jenkins pipeline? Would it please be possible for you to upload screenshots here from your configuration of the entire analysis within Jenkins and also on the other places? There can be too many differences in the configuration of sonar analysis itself that may cause this process not to work so the screenshot would be really perfect, thank you once more.

Comment: I compared my settings with the screenshot you have attached above for Sonar, the only difference is I dont have the global or inline template defined. I just use the default values there. I have added the Jenkins screenshot.

Comment: Well, I use the sonarqube scanner version for maven, which means I only invoke top level maven targets... I will try doing it and will let you know if it works.

Comment: I'm trying to apply the certification to a sonarQube but I don't know how to open the console on that particular server...

Comment: where is your sonar running? is it a Mac or windows server? 
Mac - command + space and type terminal
windows - windows+ r and type cmd

Comment: Of course I know that, the problem is I haven't created the server... Will let you know when I finally try doing that, because it's not working without importing the certificate.

Comment: @Isaiah4110, which version of SonarQube are you using? I've been trying to get this work with Jenkins and SonarQube Community Edition and I'm getting exceptions like: "To use the property "sonar.branch.name" and analyze branches, Developer Edition or above is required. "

Comment: Looks like the preview mode is no longer supported. SonarQube threw this error when I tried ' The preview mode, along with the 'sonar.analysis.mode' parameter, is no more supported. You should stop using this parameter.'